# SQL Server 2008R2 Logon failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The SS error log indicates the following at a frequency of 2 to 3 times per hour:

> Logon failed for login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' due to trigger execution. [CLIENT: ]

There is no logon trigger. How do I discover what trigger is causing the problem since the error log does not say?

(This is on a Win 7 Pro computer running SS 2008r2 developer.)

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no logon trigger? Anything at all in `sys.server_triggers`?

Comment: select * from sys.server_triggers; returns an empty table. And nothing is shown in the object explorer server objects -> triggers

Comment: Are you a sysadmin on the instance so you would definitely see all objects?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure. I connected with 'SA' account (SS authentication of course). Does this account automatically get sysadmin privilages?

Comment: The error log entry is as I posted it (except for the typo). It includes CLIENT: <local machine>

Comment: Does the error log mention the state? Seems pretty clear that it's a logon trigger (though I don't recall the exact error that's raised if the classifier function for Resource Governor fails). You may not see the logon trigger in sys.server_triggers due to permissions. On a system with logon triggers in place, it doesn't seem preposterous that those triggers would be protected by whoever created them from whoever might be trying to gain access to the system.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5   Another detail. I found one AfterLogin trigger on a table. I dropped that trigger this afternoon and since then, there have been no login failures for the mentioned NT account (or for any account). I can't yet explain why this is. The trigger was inserting data into a table including the system user. This NT account was being listed as one of the users as was the SA account and others.

Comment: So there WAS a trigger. Interesting. State 5 btw is login not found. https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: Yes, there was a trigger. But noticed that it's not a logon trigger. Rather an after logon trigger attached to a table. I read your referenced post. You indicate status 2 & 5 are very similar. One difference is that status 2 could be for Windows or SS server authentication. Status 5 you write it only indicates login user is not known to SS. Is this a real distinction? I would not expect "Network Service" to be an SS user. All this said, my explicit question is/was is there anyway to know what trigger failed? If the answer is "no" and if prior commenter wants to so state, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a trace to audit logins and/or triggers.

in case you find a trigger using this particular login the following post - [Login failed due to trigger execution](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/322151/msft-mso-logon-trigger-requires-explicit-permissions-to-be-assigned-for-users-for-its-underlying-objects) underlines the security context (see Microsoft answers) in which logon triggers are executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* you think Karl might find the post helpful? Please consider summarizing the main point of the post in your answer?